# Docker: invalid tar header

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I've created an image for docker on my Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest version of Docker (1.6.2):

```
sudo docker save 'something' > something-image.tar
```

On a mac I installed the latest Boot2docker and run this

```
docker load < something-image.tar
```

Which gives this error:

```
FATA[0489] Error response from deamon: Untar exit status 1 archive/tar: 
invalid tar header
```

Getting the same error in Windows Boot2docker, I guess something went wrong with the tar creation. **Why is this tar not working?**

Comment: doez it works on linux ?

Comment: Perhaps your linux tar does compression by default. Try it by entering `tar -tvf something-image.tar` on your linux machine. If there is an error try `tar -tvzf something-image.tar` and replace the tvzf by tvZf or tvjf until it works. It's only an idea. I'm not sure.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer yeah it works with `tvf` and lists the files in the tar

Comment: `tar -tvf` also works on mac

Comment: That's normal behavior. Ok, then how do transfer the tar to the mac? If you use ftp did you switch on the binary protocal? Ah I remember there was an issue (at least for MAC OS),  MAC OS is based on BSD so by the default there would be a BSD tar and not a GNU tar. Perhpas this helps. http://superuser.com/questions/318809/linux-os-x-tar-incompatibility-tarballs-created-on-os-x-give-errors-when-unt

Comment: "tar -tvf also works on mac": I was to quick with my last comment. But then, the save or the load command must be the problem or docker uses an own tar tool which vary on different OS. Sorry, that's a mistery to me too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was solved by updating to docker 1.7 and redoing everything.